# setup.py access files at installation-time

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

## TL;DR

I'm looking for a way to read a file content in *setup.py* that is **not part of the package** during installation time

## Description

I have a project that looks like this:

```
my_project
|--- src
      |--- my_package
               |--- ...
|--- resources
         |--- ...
|--- setup.py
```

The *resources* dir containing a list of toml files that need to be copied to the home directory during installation in order to make my code work.

Moreover, I don't want those files to be saved as part of the package in order to avoid my package from being too large.

Is including this directory in *MANIFEST.ini* and read it in *setup.py* is enough, or other actions are needed?

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: If some files need to be copied in the client $HOME by a script at installation time I don't see how you could ship and access those files if they are not bundled in your package. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `MANIFEST.in` (no `i` and the end) makes the files part of your package. So either they're a part and you can read them; or they are not and you cannot.